# Como guardo los datos que contiene un GridView en una base de datos sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Estoy intentando guardar los datos que tiene mi gridview en la Base de datos, pero al guardar no captura los datos, me guarda vacío.

Mediante un formulario voy agregando N filas con varios datos al gridview, luego lo que hago es guardad en la BD todas esas filas con sus datos, pero el problema es que me está guardando los datos vacíos, no me está capturando lo que tengo almacenado en el GridView.

Antes me funcionaba perfecto, pero porque generaba automáticamente las columnas desde el código, pero cambié el gridview generando las columnas en el HMTL para poder meter los botones de eliminar y editar, usando TemplateField y EditItemTemplate.

```
//Este es el codigo de como estoy intentando guardar en la BD
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    SqlCommand agregarSolicitud = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO solicitudes VALUES(@id_encabezado_solicitud, @material_modelo, @tipo_material, @nombre_espanol, @nombre_ingles, @unidad_medida_base, @grupo_articulos, @numero_pieza_fabricante, @fabricante, @caracteristica_plan_nec, @punto_pedido, @tamano_lote, @stock_maximo, @valor_redondeo, @categoria_valoracion, @tipo_valoracion, @precio_estandar)", Conexion.Open());
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.Clear();
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_encabezado_solicitud", Convert.ToString(txtIdSolicitud.Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@material_modelo", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_material", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_espanol", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre_ingles", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unidad_medida_base", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[5].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grupo_articulos", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[6].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero_pieza_fabricante", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[7].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fabricante", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[8].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@caracteristica_plan_nec", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[9].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@punto_pedido", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[10].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tamano_lote", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[11].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock_maximo", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[12].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor_redondeo", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[13].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("categoria_valoracion", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[14].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_valoracion", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[15].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@precio_estandar", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[16].Text));
    agregarSolicitud.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Y este es el de mi gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed" Width="1100px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Material modelo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Material modelo]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Material modelo]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tipo Material">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Tipo Material]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Tipo Material]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre en Español">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Nombre en Español]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Nombre en Español]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nombre en Ingles">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Nombre en Ingles]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Nombre en Ingles]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unidad Medida Base">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Unidad Medida Base]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Unidad Medida Base]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Grupo de Articulos">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Grupo de Articulos]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Grupo de Articulos]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Numero de pieza fabricante">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Numero de pieza fabricante]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Numero de pieza fabricante]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fabricante">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fabricante") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Fabricante") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="carac plan nec">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[carac plan nec]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[carac plan nec]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Punto pedido">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Punto pedido]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Punto pedido]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tamaño lote">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[tamaño lote]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[tamaño lote]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stock Maximo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Stock Maximo]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Stock Maximo]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Valor de redondeo">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Valor de redondeo]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Valor de redondeo]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Categoria de valoracion">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Categoria de valoracion]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Categoria de valoracion]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tipo de valoracion">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[tipo de valoracion]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[tipo de valoracion]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="precio estandar">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[precio estandar]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[precio estandar]") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Eliminar">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button CommandName="delete" runat="server"
                    ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-danger" Text="Eliminar" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" HeaderText="Editar" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-primary">
            <ControlStyle CssClass="btn btn-primary"></ControlStyle>
        </asp:CommandField>
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo pude solucionar, el problema estaba que solo estaba llamando la posición en el gridview, también debía llamar al control, de esta manera:

Asignamos una variable tipo Label a la posición y el control y luego en nuestro código de guardar llamamos a la variable con su propiedad tipo Text.

`Label lbl1 = row.Cells[0].FindControl("Label1") as Label;`

`agregarSolicitud.Parameters.AddWithValue("@material_modelo", lbl1.Text);`